# Joomla - Automatically log users in using $_GET variables

Tags: php, authentication, get, joomla1.5

I know this sounds very dumb, but we have a client that sends out newsletters. But the target market is extremely computer illiterate, so the client requires us to embed the login details in the urls on the newsletter so users can be logged in automatically in the Joomla front-end.

What I have propsed is that we simply do a script which gets the username and password from the url using $_GET and then how can I pass it to the $my object which gets created only once the user logs in through the Joomla login page?

Obviously, I'm not getting everything here code-related, but the concept stays the same, we want to automatically log people in using a url and then if it could redirect them to the page they wanted to go, all in one sweep.

Thanks in advance for any comments & advice.

Comment: You could write an authentication plugin to handle that for you.  But I must warn you that what you're asking to do could be abused and can lead to issues...  What if someone forwards the email to a friend?  Then they are automatically logged in as that person?  I'd look for another solution, or at least try to actually define the problem at hand...

Comment: This is stupid in terms of security.

Comment: I can't help you with Joomla, however it will be better if you send some kind of use-once unique-id and login using that. I would not return to a website that placed my username and password plain-text at url.

Comment: You should seriously warn the client that this will create liability problems legally. If the user accounts contain any personal information this would be a MAJOR problem that could land your client in court. You could expose yourself to some liability as well, there is no way I would do this for a client. At the very least you should make the client sign a release of liability.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is terrible in terms of security, but all you'd need to do is pass

```
login.php?username=X&password=Y
```

And change your login to accept $_REQUEST instead of $_POST

```
$username = $_REQUEST['username'];
$password = $_REQUEST['password'];

$loggedIn = User::Login($username, $password);
```

But again, this is TERRIBLE from a security standpoint.

If you really need a fast way to do this, you should consider emailing them a hash of some salt and their username and then logging them in that way. Something like this:

```
login.php?user=aw48hgghsudghaw9eg
```

Then

```
$hash = $_GET['user'];
$result = mysql_query("SELECT username, password 
                       FROM users 
                       WHERE md5("SALT_STRING", username) = $hash");
if (mysql_num_rows($result)) {
    $row = mysql_result($result);
    $loggedIn = User::Login($row['username'], $row['$password']);
}
```

Or something similar.

Comment: Even that's not great IMHO (Since if someone figures out your salt, they can login as anyone they wish)...  I'd rather see a one-time-use token generated that's stored in another table (which is removed once it's used).  Then again, I'd rather not see this done at all since it kind of defeats the purpose of authentication in the first place...

Comment: I agree with you completely on both fronts o.O Also, thanks for the edit.

Comment: I know, this is a severe FAIL in terms of security, but the client requires a login but wants her users to able to login automatically from an email.

Answer (score 1):

```
        $mainframe = JFactory::getApplication();
        $credentials = array(); 
        $credentials['username']  =  $app->input->get('username', '', 'string');
        $credentials['password']  = $app->input->get('password',  '', 'raw');
        $mainframe->login($credentials);
        //$mainframe->redirect(JRoute::_('index.php', false));
```